# Change default DNS in azure storage java jar

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage

I have added the azure-storage-6.1.0.jar as external libraries in my java project.

In the azure storage jar, there is a class file called CloudStorageAccount.class which contains  static field.

```
private static final String DEFAULT_DNS = "core.windows.net";
```

And it always maps this to the URL to form  https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer

How can i change or over ride this so that it looks something like below

https://changedURL/mycontainer

Please provide any suggestions.

Regards,

Sridhar

Comment: Hi,any updates?

Answer (score 0):

As we know , `DEFAULT_DNS` is a string variable decorated by the `final` keyword that cannot be changed or override.

However , you could define custom `EndpointSuffix` in the connectionString: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net` when you init CloudStorageAccount.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
```

Please refer to the `getStorageUri` method in the [CloudStorageAccount.class source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/abfae32024eced2a82d7cc83dddf0a3ca2c2176e/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/CloudStorageAccount.java#L305).

Hope it helps you.